# TFS download files greater 1GB

Tags: tfs

When we try to download a file greater than 1 GB from the TFS Web Access (TFS 2013 Update 4) we get an "ArithmeticException" error.
On MSDN it says that Update 4 will fix this, but we still have this problem.

Here is some Data from IIS Failed Request Tracing:

```
        &lt;title&gt;Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width&quot; /&gt;
    &lt;style&gt;
     body {font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;} 
     p {font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     b {font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
     H1 { font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
     H2 { font-family:&quot;Verdana&quot;;font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
     pre {font-family:&quot;Consolas&quot;,&quot;Lucida Console&quot;,Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
     .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
     .version {color: gray;}
     .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
     .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
     @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
      pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
     }
     @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
      pre { width: 280px; }
     }
    &lt;/style&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;

&lt;body bgcolor=&quot;white&quot;&gt;

        &lt;span&gt;&lt;H1&gt;Server Error in &apos;/tfs&apos; Application.&lt;hr width=100% size=1 color=silver&gt;&lt;/H1&gt;

        &lt;h2&gt; &lt;i&gt;Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.&lt;/i&gt; &lt;/h2&gt;&lt;/span&gt;

        &lt;font face=&quot;Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif &quot;&gt;

        &lt;b&gt; Description: &lt;/b&gt;An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

        &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;

        &lt;b&gt; Exception Details: &lt;/b&gt;System.ArithmeticException: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;

        &lt;b&gt;Source Error:&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;

        &lt;table width=100% bgcolor=&quot;#ffffcc&quot;&gt;
           &lt;tr&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;
                  &lt;code&gt;

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.&lt;/code&gt;

              &lt;/td&gt;
           &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;/table&gt;

        &lt;br&gt;

        &lt;b&gt;Stack Trace:&lt;/b&gt; &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;

        &lt;table width=100% bgcolor=&quot;#ffffcc&quot;&gt;
           &lt;tr&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;
                  &lt;code&gt;&lt;pre&gt;

[ArithmeticException: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.]

[HttpException (0x80004005): An error occurred while communicating with the remote host. The error code is 0x80070216.]
   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.RaiseCommunicationError(Int32 result, Boolean throwOnDisconnect) +4666760
   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.FlushCore(Boolean keepConnected, Int32 numBodyFragments, IntPtr[] bodyFragments, Int32[] bodyFragmentLengths, Int32[] bodyFragmentTypes) +11927421
   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.FlushCachedResponse(Boolean isFinal) +782
   System.Web.HttpResponse.UpdateNativeResponse(Boolean sendHeaders) +558
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequestNotification(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context, RequestNotificationStatus&amp;amp; status) +185
```

Comment: Storing a 1gb file in Source Control is neither recommended nor a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you to update to the final version for TFS2013  [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013 with Update 5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48150) which will fix some issues in update4.

And also [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/)  and IE cache, then try the download again.

Comment: The Problem is still there. See Failed Request Tracing Log in the Question